# Performing a Sum of COUNT after GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT > 1

Tags: mysql

I have this following query which I want to SUM the count table for any counts that are greater than 1.  I'm not sure exactly how to go about doing this:

```
SELECT  count(id) as count, 
        id, 
        location_id, 
        time, 
        weekofyear(time) 


from table where weekofyear(time) = '28' 
group by location_id, id
having count > 1
order by count desc
```

Results:

```
count   id  location_id time    weekofyear(time)
5   32265   409 7/12/14 3:58    28
5   32266   409 7/12/14 3:59    28
5   27532   399 7/12/14 4:54    28
4   31124   41  7/7/14 4:41 28
```

So I would like the sum to show 19

Comment: What is your desired result ?

Comment: The result of your sample data should be 19. Just select from your query - in other words: use a subselect.

Comment: Sorry, yes I would like the result to be 19.  Not sure how to do a subselect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple subselect from your own query should do it:

```
SELECT
   SUM(t.count)
FROM (
    SELECT  count(id) as count, 
            id, 
            location_id, 
            time, 
            weekofyear(time) 
    from table where weekofyear(time) = '28' 
    group by location_id, id
    having count > 1
) as t
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Now you've learned that you can query the result of an query too. If you accept my answer then your question will be taken off the list of unanswerer questions and may help others in the same situation as yours.

Comment: my next question would be, how do I sum the count and group by weekofyear(time)?  Would I just add that clause to the end of the entire query?